# What are ways to include sizable Postgres table imports in Flyway migrations?

Tags: postgresql, flyway

We have a series of modifications to a Postgres database, which can generally be written all in SQL. So it seems Flyway would be a great fit to automate these.

However, they also include imports from files to tables, such as

```
COPY mytable FROM '${PWD}/mydata.sql';
```

And secondarily, we'd like not to rely on Postgres' use of file paths like this, which apparently must reside on the server. It should be possible to run any migration from a remote client -- as in [Amazon's RDS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Procedural.Importing.html) (last section).

Are there good approaches to handling this kind of scenario already in Flyway? Or alternate approaches to avoid this issue altogether?

Currently, it looks like it'd work to implement the whole migration in Java and use the Postgres driver's CopyManager to import the data. However, that means most of our migrations have to be done in Java, which seems much clumsier. (As far as I can tell, hybrid Java+SQL migrations are not expected?)

Am new to looking at Flyway so thought I'd ask what other alternatives might exist with Flyway, since I'd expect it's pretty common to import a table during a migration.

Comment: Can you run `psql` from within Flyway? Then you could use psql's `\copy` command which takes files from the client. Another option is to put the table data _into_ the SQL script and use `COPY from stdin` (which is essentially the same as psql's `\copy` command (but `copy from stdin` also only works from within psql, the JDBC driver does not support this if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: Good suggestions. Have thought about both of those, but the latter doesn't work with Flyway currently, and I'm not sure how to do the former (without just writing a Java migration). I guess I wish there were Bash migrations! All of this is easily doable in Bash plus a couple files.

Comment: Postscript: After some experimentation, we switched to Python's yoyo-migrations instead. Removing Java customization from this part of the deploy chain made life much easier for us. We were able to customize migrations to our needs easily, as well as handle additional features like downloading dumps from S3, without requiring new compile steps for each adjustment.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Flyway 3.1, you can use COPY FROM STDIN statements within your migration files to accomplish this. The SQL execution engine will automatically use PostgreSQL's CopyManager to transfer the data.